# Test a function with different list of value with quickCheck

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

I need to test a function with `quickCheck` with different range of values.

my function is :

```
prop_test (x,y,z) (i,j,k) ndiv
```

and I would like to perform tests with :

- **x,y,z** randomly taken in the range **0** to **1000**
- **i,j,k** randomly taken in the range **1000** to **100000**
- **ndiv** randomly taken in a list of fixed values **[2,5,10,20]**

I managed to set one property for one argument, but I didn't find how to set multiple (different) property to the function.

Comment: can you give us the code you tried? It's easier to point you to the right way to do it this way. Aside from this you can also just get 7 random (non-negative?) integers and use a bit integer/modulo arithmetic to bring them into your desired ranges ;) (and there are functions in QuickCheck to massage the generators into that too)

Comment: For example, to test a function `f` on the domain [0..1000] you could do something like `prop_f = forAll (choose (0, 1000)) f`. You can chain `forAll`s for each value you need to generate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simpler example that you should be able to adapt to your style. Assuming you have a function

```
f :: Int -> Int -> Bool
```

and you want to test if `f x y` evaluates to `True` for `x` in the range `0` to `10` and `y` in the range `10` to `20`, you can do that by saying

```
prop_f :: Property
prop_f = forAll (choose ( 0, 10)) $ \ x ->
         forAll (choose (10, 20)) $ \ y ->
         f x y
```

Another option is to combine the generation of several values into one `forAll` call by constructing a new generator on the fly:

```
prop_f :: Property
prop_f = forAll ((,) <$> r1 <*> r2) $ \ (x, y) -> f x y
  where
    r1 = choose ( 0, 10)
    r2 = choose (10, 20)
```

Yet another option is to define your own newtype wrappers:

```
newtype R1 = R1 Int
newtype R2 = R2 Int

instance Arbitrary R1 where arbitrary = R1 <$> choose ( 0, 10)
instance Arbitrary R2 where arbitrary = R2 <$> choose (10, 20)

prop_f :: R1 -> R2 -> Bool
prop_f (R1 x) (R2 y) = f x y
```

To define a generator that uses a predefined list of options, you'll have to use the `elements` functions.

Comment: I searched in hackage for `<$>` function but I didn't find it. Which module import this function ?

Comment: @JeanJouX Use Hoogle to search for functions: https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%3C%24%3E The operator `<$>` is just another name for `fmap`. It's defined in `Data.Functor` and re-exported from `Control.Applicative` (which also defines `<*>`).